# $q.all returns same response for all promises in the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-http

I'm facing some difficulties while trying to understand why $q.all returns the response of the last promise in array, for all promises given:

```
function getGlobalData() {
    $q.all(
        [
        genericApi.submitPostRequest(getPostData('firstKey')),
        genericApi.submitPostRequest(getPostData('secondKey')),
        genericApi.submitPostRequest(getPostData('specialKey'))
        ])
    .then(function(results){
        vm.globalObject['firstKey'] = results[0].data;
        vm.globalObject['secondKey'] = results[1].data;
        vm.globalObject['specialKey'] = results[2].data;
    });
}
```

End-points are all the same, the only thing I change on each request is one element (key element) in 'postData' object.

```
function submitPostRequest(data) {    
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        data: data,
        url: 'https://someUrl',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: 'Bearer someToken'
        }
    });
}
```

postData :

```
var postRequest = {
  'endtime' : null,
  'key' : null, 
  'arr' : ['diff','core'],
  'starttime' : null
};
```

getPostData:

```
function getPostData(key){
    postRequest.key = key;
    return postRequest;
}
```

Comment: There aren't enough informations to detect the error. The best guess I personally can do is that there likely is something wrong here: `genericApi.submitPostRequest(getPostData('firstKey'))`. I would suggest you to add additional logs inside `submitPostRequest` and `getPostData` and to **inspect requests and responses using the "network" tab of any browser**. In this way, you will be able to undestand whether your code is doing something wrong **while sending the request**, whether the **server is responding with the same values** or whether **you are not acquiring values correctly**.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I already tried to do these steps. I couldn't find anything wrong, that's why I came here to hear another opinion. please let me know what additional info is needed.

Comment: If you've checked those points, can you detect on which of the three above the problem relies? more importantly, are the responses different?

Comment: Responses are all the same, I can see in 'Network Tab', that the same request which is the last one in the array, was sent 3 times.

Comment: Please show `getPostData`, if the request is the same, getPostData is probably missing something.

Comment: Sure, I made an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `angular.copy` to make a new copy of the data for each request:

```
function getPostData(key){
    var req = angular.copy(postRequest);
    req.key = key;
    return req;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is happening because `postRequest` is global, hence the object is altered three times but the same object is used. Either use `angular.copy`, either use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`, either just declare the object inline.

```
function getPostData(key){
   var postRequest = {
     'endtime' : null,
     'key' : null, 
     'arr' : ['diff','core'],
     'starttime' : null
   };
   postRequest.key = key;
   return postRequest;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for that. Obviously, I can't accept both answers so i'll go with the one posted first.

Comment: Not commenting on the quality of either answer, but don't accept an answer just because it came first - accept the answer that [helped you the most](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262285/1364007). Otherwise (again, not commenting on the answers here) there's no point ever having more than one answer per question.